# Why does my Mercurial tag not show up in the list of tags?

Tags: tags, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a Mercurial repository which has several tags. Those tags are used for release management and all contain version numbers. All tags are always added on the default branch. Here is an excerpt from my `.hgtags` file:

```
55d0e566170f61935088c301ced8137b17868171 1.63
d898fc03cefa0becb880e0ad214d80aec22b79df 1.64
dfef02cc4a2f8e34ba9e34c782299708d8ec68b7 1.65
f0519f072992c39346b65332e444492fc5694e14 1.66
6537785f8093c0f3b55df0e41bb5586aa104bd9f 1.66.1
```

For some reason, the `1.66` tag does not show up in TortoiseHg and neither in `hg tags`. I could make it show up by adding it again via TortoiseHg which creates the additional two lines in the file:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.66
f0519f072992c39346b65332e444492fc5694e14 1.66
```

As you can see, the hash of the newly created tag is still he same as the one of the old tag.

Why does the existing tag not show up? Clearing the `.hg/cache` directory did not help.

Comment: Is there another line in your .hgtags file which removes the tag, i.e. `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.66` ?

Comment: @planetmaker No, this is the only line for 1.66

Comment: Mercurial uses the .hgtags files from all branch heads, so perhaps the tag is deleted in another head?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't think it is. Is there any easy way to find out or do I have to check out each branch head manually?

Comment: On Windows, you could do the following to list the contents of `.hgtags` on each topological head:  `for /f %r in ('hg heads -t -T {rev}\n') do @hg cat .hgtags -r %r`.  Then inspect the result for a delete of the tag.

Comment: I had the same issue, clearing out the .hg/cache folder worked for me.  Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the same tag name was (mistakenly) previously used for a local tag on this repository, but subsequently deleted. Therefore, there was a line which deleted the tag in `.hg/localtags`. It seems this overrides non-local tags as well. Removing the offending lines from the `localtags` file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you *update to* a particular tag, the tag itself vanishes.  This is a natural consequence of the way Mercurial *stores* tags, which is in a revision-controlled file.  See [the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Tag) for additional examples, but in short:

```
hg up -r 1.66
```

takes you to the revision that was tagged `1.66`, which itself has a `.hgtags` file that does *not* have the entry for `1.66` in it, because the revision you've just updated-to was created *before* the name `1.66` itself went into `.hgtags`.  Presumably, this is what is happening here.  (Edit per comments: apparently not.  I assumed that because you were showing the lines from the file, you were mainly looking at the file.  Now it's pretty mysterious.)

Note: when using a tag name like `1.66` as a `--rev` option, or running `hg tags`, Mercurial scans *all* heads for *all* their `.hgtags` files.  There is some complicated code to cache the result since this scan is expensive, but the effect is that `hg tags` *should* list the tag, even if you can't see it in the `.hgtags` file.

---

When you go to create it the tag again, Mercurial first deletes the old tag (that's the all-zeros line), then creates the new tag with the same hash ID in it (that's the `f0519f072992c39346b65332e444492fc5694e14`) line.  The new `.hgtags` contents goes into a new commit.  Updating to `1.66` should make *all three* lines vanish from the file, since the `.hgtags` file in `f0519f072992c39346b65332e444492fc5694e14` is a version of that file that has no occurrences of `1.66`.  But as long as you are updated to the head, instead of to tag `1.66`, you will now see all three lines.  Meanwhile `hg tags` should continue to list the tag.

Comment: I understand that the revision of the tag cannot see its own tag, but my problem is that the tag cannot be seen by child revisions of the tagged revision, not even when the default head revision is checked out.

Comment: Interesting ... that shouldn't happen, *provided* that you update (or have your GUI update) to the actual head, rather than the tagged version. Does the problem go away if you use the command line, instead of TortoiseHg?

Comment: I checked using the command line and the tag does not show up in `hg tags` if that is what you mean.

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I meant, but is sufficient: that *should have* shown the tag.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding as well and it works for all the other tags except this one, tags which are both older and newer than that one. Do you have any more ideas how I could debug this?

Comment: If you're (very) familiar with Python you can run `hg --debugger tags` and then use pdb to step through the code. The function that retrieves the tags list is `742 B->     def tagslist(self):` (line numbers will vary a bit), which is a method in a repo object. This eventually invokes `findglobaltags`, which may use the cached result, or build it.